# xamarin forms await não é respeitado

Tags: c#, sql-insert, xamarin-forms

Boa noite,

alguém me sabe dizer porque o código abaixo não respeita o Wait, em debug
a ordem de saída é

  *1. init save*
  *2. End Save*
  *3. New header ID: 1*

em vez de:

  *1. init save*
  *2. New header ID: 1*
  *3. End Save*

```
public async Task Save(Ticket header, TicketLines newLines)
{
                Debug.WriteLine("init save");
                await dbConnection.RunInTransactionAsync(new Action<SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection>(tran =>
                {
                    dbConnection.InsertAsync(header).ContinueWith((t) =>
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("New header ID: {0}", header.Id);                       
                        foreach (var item in newLines)
                        {
                            item.DocumentId = header.Id;
                        }
                        dbConnection.InsertAllAsync(newLines);                     
                    });
                    //tran.Commit();                    
                }));
                Debug.WriteLine("End Save");

}
```

Eu quero chamar o metodo **Save** e no final mando refrescar a tela, o que acontece como ele não respeita a o Await eu mando refrescar a tela e ainda não inserir os dados

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade, o que está acontecendo é que você não está esperando a função `InsertAsync`, então programa segue o fluxo normal e imprime `End Save`, como esperado.

A saída que você deseja requer que a chamada a `InsertAsync` tenha terminado, e `ContinueWith` tenha começado. Pra isso, basta inserir um `await` antes de `dbConnection.InsertAsync`. Com isso, a execução desse método vai ser interrompida até que `ContinueWith` seja completada.

Atenção: `dbConnection.InsertAsync(...).ContinueWith(...)` retorna um `awaitable` que se refere à chamada `ContinueWith`, e não `InserAsync`.